# jQuery slideDown for posts on index page? (Wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, post, slidedown

I'm doing a one page website in wordpress and there I want to display only one post on the index page with a summary of the post. For that I know I can change the_content to the_excerpt in the loop.php. But when I click on "Continue Reading" I come to a new page and that is not what I want. I want the div to slide down and display the whole news on the page.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the relevant html? It's been a while since I even thought about Wordpress... It might be doable with a `fadeOut()`, `load()` and `fadeIn()` though. Also: while this **is not** a vote to close, the [Wordpress Stack Exchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) might have access to better suggestions, or previous questions on the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution ( not the best ) :

Display the_excerpt() in a visible div , display the_content() in a hidden div , on "continue reading" click ( using jquery ) togle animation .

Answer (score 0):

I would output both the excerpt and the content, each to its own `div` tag. Class them accordingly, and hide the content `div.content` in your CSS file. Now, put a *read more* link after these two `div`'s and then link a handler to the *read more* where you hide the excerpt `div.excerpt` and show the content `div.content` in one motion:

```
$("a.readmore").click(function () {
    $(this).prev().prev("div.excerpt").hide();
    $(this).prev("div.content").show();
    // EDIT:
    return false; // this will stop default behaviour of jumping to the top of page for instance
}
```

Hope this puts you on the right path. Here my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/FANVp/6/. Like poelinca says, not the best but it'll work.

Comment: When I do this i get to the top of the page when I click on the read_more link... That's not good. Should it be like that or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The content is showing but I'm coming to the top of the page and I have to scroll down to se the post again.

Comment: Just add `return: false;` to the end of the function, after the third line. This suppresses the default browser action induced by clicking a link with `#` as the target.

Comment: Do what Gavin said, I just forgot to add it. Will edit my answer now.